# Monotonicity of eigenvalues II

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

In a previous question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418265/monotonicity-of-eigenvalues), I asked the question below for block matrices and received an answer showing the question is true if $\mathcal B$ is hermitian and false, in general if $\mathcal B$ is non-hermitian. However, numerical experiments suggest it is still true if we are talking only about matrices rather than block matrices and this is the content of this question.
We consider matrices
$$\mathcal A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\\bar a& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$\mathcal B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b\\c & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
with $a,b,c \in \mathbb C.$

Then we define the new matrix
$$T(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \mathcal A+t & \mathcal B \\ \mathcal B^* & \mathcal A-t\end{pmatrix}.$$

Numerical experiments seem to show that the eigenvalues of $[0,\infty) \ni t\mapsto T(t)$ have the property that their absolute values are monotonically increasing in $t \ge 0.$ However, I do not have a proof of this, does anybody know how this follows? (The eigenvalues of $T(t)$ seem to come in pairs $\pm \lambda$ with $\lambda = \lambda(t) \ge 0$, i.e. $+\lambda(t)$ is increasing, while $-\lambda(t)$ is decreasing.

To illustrate the effect, consider

$$T(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
  t & 1& 0& 2\\
  1 & t & 0&  0\\
  0 & 0& -t & 1\\
  2& 0 &  1 & -t 
\end{pmatrix},$$ then the eigenvalues of $T(t)$ are
$$ \pm 1 \mp \sqrt{2+t^2}.$$

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How does this new question differ from [1] ?

Comment: @KurtG. [1] is about block-matrices, the question has been answered when $B$ is self-adjoint and shown to be false when $B$ is not self-adjoint (in general). Here, I consider now the case that $A$ and $B$ are not block matrices but matrices, in which case the statement still seems to hold, even when $B$ is not hermitian.

Comment: The previous question was too general so that it was false in general and true in the special case of $B$ self-adjoint. The new question is a special case of the previous question, but hopefully true even if $B$ is not self-adjoint. The self-adjoint case is already proven.

Comment: @KurtG. sure, I think I did this 5 minutes ago, right? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is even in both $X$ and $t$ : $P_t(X)=Q(X^2,t^2)$ where
$$Q(Y,s)=(Y-s)^2-(2|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2)(Y-s)-4|a|^2s+|a^2-b\bar c|^2.$$
The variation of $s\mapsto Y(s)$ is given by the derivative
$$2(Y-s)(Y'-1)-(2|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2)(Y'-1)-4|a|^2=0.$$
The sign of $Y'$ changes when $s$ crosses the value
$$s_0=\frac1{4|a|^2}(2|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2)(2|a|^2-|b|^2-|c|^2).$$
This value is admissible for $t_0^2$ if it is positive, that is is $2|a|^2>|b|^2+|c|^2$.

In conclusion, the absolute values of the eigenvalues are monotonous functions of $s$ whenever  $2|a|^2\le|b|^2+|c|^2$. If on the contrary $2|a|^2>|b|^2+|c|^2$, then one of the eigenvalues is not monotone, and the change happens when $t$ crosses
$$t_0=\frac1{2|a|}\sqrt{(2|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2)(2|a|^2-|b|^2-|c|^2)}.$$

Comment: Nice work. Deleted my answer because I only ended up calculating the same characteristic polynomial.